rows to column / data transpose
Any code for this one? I need help. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks
I want to transpose all data in a row after a blank / space in column 1.
If a row in column1 has data then the following data in column 2 with blank data in row which belongs to column 1 will be transposed.
Image 1
and will end up to
Image 2

You might want to help people out providing more information on the app / language you want to use.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
